# $http post return status code 204 no content Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a problem while posting the data to server using `$http.post`. It's returning the status code 204 no Content. I am doing something wrong. In the success callback it's not showing the response.

```
$scope.prod = {},

$scope.AddProduct = function (prod) {
    var data = prod;
    $http.post('/api/Product', JSON.stringify(data), {
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    })
}
```

});[image: Browser Response while posting]

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect?

Comment: This depends on your server configuration, e.g. Spring Data REST does not return a response on POST by default.

Comment: its not saving new  data to database.

Comment: add your spring controller to your question

Comment: force to change status to 200?